# Disabling SSL Certificate Validation in SpringBoot 3.0 RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot

I'm migrating my application to Springboot 3.0.

```java
public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true ;
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial( null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build() ;
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory( sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE ) ;
            
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
              .register("https", sslsf)           
              .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
              .build();

    BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
                    HttpClients.custom()
                               .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                               .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                               .build();
         
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return requestFactory;
}
```

In the package
`org.springframework.http.client` class missing  `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`;

What's in SpringBoot 3.0.x instead of `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` ?

regards

Comment: It should be available. ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html please add your dependencies so we can check it out.